# KDB query performance improvement

Tags: c#, performance, kdb

I have a simple table containing prices that I'm using for stock algo back testing.

```
price_hist:([pxkey:`$()]price:`float$())
update `g#pxkey from `price_hist
```

pxkey is a concatenated string in the format 'MSFT_5M_201710060945', so stock=MSFT, price bar intervals=5 mins and datetime=201710060945. I used the concatenated string instead of individual columns because it's simple and I'm a KDB novice and I wanted to get something running quickly.

I have about 5 million rows in there and the performance is only marginally faster than MySql using the exact same data. Any ideas on how to improve this (either thru table structure, attributes, query, anything..)? FYI I'm using C# with qSharp library and to query i'm using this format which returns a dictionary:-

```
price_hist`MSFT_5M_201710060945
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating millions of generated symbols is never a good idea in kdb+.  I would recommend using a keyed table instead of a dictionary:

```
bar5m:([sym:`$();time:`timestamp$()]price:`float$())
```

Once you populate it, you should be able to query it as follows

```
bar5m[(`MSFT;2017.10.06D09:45);`price]
```

To improve the performance, make sure the table is sorted by `sym,time` and put the `p` attribute on `sym`.

Comment: In my case price_hist is also a keyed table tho, right? So the difference in you suggestion is using separate string and datetime columns as keys [and also splitting the into different tables for bars]. Separate string and datetime columns would have a big impact on performance?

Comment: Technically, a keyed table is a dictionary in kdb+.  It is a mapping from one table to another.  If those tables have a single column, the keyed table is almost indistinguishable from a simple dictionary.  The main suggestion in my answer is not to use composed symbols, but use multiple key columns.

Comment: Understood - I will try that (and probably be back with a followup). Oh one more thing.. could u perhaps give me a quick syntax to create a the new table from the existing data? It would mean converting the string to date. It would probably take me a couple of hours to get it right but you 20 seconds! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I tried your suggestion and performance is no faster. Maybe I haven't set up the attributes properly. Here's what I've done:- `bar5m:s#([inst:$();time:timestamp$()]price:float$()) 
bar5m insert (insttime xasc select from price_hist_bar5m)
update p#inst from bar5m`